# FATAL: database "[DB]" does not exist on remote connection

Tags: postgresql, remote-access

I'm running a postgresql database on our server. I know the error is common if you do not specify a database and haven't created on with the same name as your user. If I ssh into the server I can successfully access the database (`DB`).

However, if I try to connect remotely, I get `FATAL: database "[DB]" does not exist`, but it does exists, since I can access it on the server. It does not matter which username I choose, I always get the message.

*Command to connect:*

```
psql --host="192.168.1.XXX" --port="5433" --dbname="[DB]" -U postgres
```

*Contents of `pg_hba.conf`:*

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             192.168.1.1/16          trust

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

*Contents of `postgresql.conf` (excerpt):*

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5433
max_connections = 100

ssl = true
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'
```

*The output from `\l` (abbreviated):*

```
  Name   |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
---------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
  DB     | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 |  postgres=CTc/postgres
```

*The output from `\du`:*

```
                               List of roles
 Role name   |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
 ------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
  admin      | Create role, Create DB                         | {}
  <username> | Create role, Create DB                         | {admin}
  postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

`<username>` is the user name on my computer and server.

Comment: Are you in the same network segment as your pg server? Can you access a different db? Can you try connect with pgAdmin using a windows pc?

Comment: Why is it saying `database "[DB]" does not exist` rather than `database "DB" does not exist`? Is something trying to use SQL Server style bracket quoting?

Comment: Yes, I'm in the same network. I cannot access any other db. Unfortunately I only have a mac and the Ubuntu server. The `"[DB]"` was purely formatting from my side to hide the real db name and to indicate it did not matter which db I try to connect to. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your `pg_hba.conf` you've set the authentication method to `trust`. As per the the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html):

> When trust authentication is specified, PostgreSQL assumes that anyone who can connect to the server is authorized to access the database with whatever database user name they specify (even superuser names)

It appears that using this authentication method hides the database when accessing it remotely.

The solution here is to use [password authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-password.html), which can be specified as `md5`, `scram-sha-256`, or `password` for sending the password in clear-text.

So your `pg_hba.conf` should look like this:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             192.168.1.1/16          md5

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```